# How to match a new string with the password already encrypted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, devise

I am working on a rails 3.2.13 project. I am using devise plugin (devise gem 3.2.2, 1.4.2) for authentication. Using this plugin, how can I validate the `current_password` field while changing the old password to a new one? Or else, please suggest how I can achieve this by encrypting the given string and matching it with the password already saved without using the devise plugin.

E.g.: One user has `encrypted_password` like below:

```
"$2a$10$VrawKYj6zp10XUxbixVzE.7d4QgYjQn9aiuzAuP7fp3PZOLMP5wbu"
```

while changing the password, if I enter a `current_password`, it should match the string above (`encrypted_password` == `current_password`). How can I validate this?

Comment: I think devise automatically provides this. When you go to the edit_user_registration_path.

Comment: I am not getting it. The thing is, I need to validate totally 3 fields, old_password, new_password, confirm_new_password. New password fields are validating fine but the issue is with the old_password field.

Comment: Yeah, it should be there. Check this out: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to break your problem down into the following steps:

#### Determine if the `old_password` is actually the user's current password.

To do this, you can call:

```
User.find_by_id([SOME_ID]).valid_password?(old_password)
```

If this returns true, then you can move on to the next step to begin changing of the password.  If it doesn't, then the `old_password` is incorrect, and you should not allow the changing of password.

The implementation of `valid_password?` can be found in the Devise gem's `/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb` file (at around Line 40).  You could use this implementation to roll your own code for validating a password.  But, Devise pretty much does it for you if you call `valid_password?`, so rolling your own seems unnecessary.

#### If `old_password` is valid, then verify that `new_password` matches `confirm_new_password`.

```
if (new_password == confirm_new_password)
   .
   .
   .
end
```

#### If these match, then set the new password by doing the following:

```
u = User.find_by_id([SOME ID])
u.password = new_password
u.password_confirmation = confirm_new_password
u.save
```

#### You can verify that the password has been changed by:

```
u.valid_password?(new_password)
```

Comment: Right now validation is not happening, if I fix the validation issue then another issue will occur i.e. new_password will accept only old_password, I am not able to enter different password.

Answer (score 0):

Update user with current_password validation:

```
@user.update_with_password(account_update_params)
# account_update_params - should have :current_password, :password, :password_confirmation
```

It is default behaviour in Devise::RegistrationsController. If you want update user without password, you should overwrite controller's action

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    # resource.update_with_password(params)
    resource.update_attributes(params)
  end
end
```

---

Do I understand you right what you want allow users login with encrypted and unencrypted (usual) password?

We have:

```
user.valid_password?('Password2').should
```

[code on github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/bf5bcd52cb9edaefb002927434d7ede398e74bc5/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L46)

So we can overwrite it inside models/user.rb

```
def valid_password?(password)
  encrypted_password == password || super(password)
end
```

Comment: I have tried whatever u mentioned, validations are working fine but the issue is, I can't change a old password to new password. If I enter all 3 fields with the same current(existing) password then it will accept otherwise, if I enter different password in new_password & confirm_password field it will show current_password is invalid.